# Laravel, check if form values have been changed by the client before sending them to Paypal

Tags: php, laravel, validation, security, paypal

I have a form with input values to send to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. The problem is that they can be edited on the client side with the inspector. So how to check in Laravel 8.x, if the input values have been changed before I make the request to Paypal?

```
<form id="fFlightPrice" method="post" action="{{ env('PAYPAL_FORM_URL') }}">
    <div class="my-3">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="RB_BuyNow_WPS_IT">
        <input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="0.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{{ env('PAYPAL_BUSINNESS_EMAIL') }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="IT">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{{ route(P::ROUTE_PAYPAL_RETURN) }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Torna al sito">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="{{ route(P::ROUTE_PAYPAL_CANCEL) }}">
    </div>
    <div class="my-3">
        @forelse($flights as $flight)
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_{{ $loop->iteration }}" value="{{ $flight['name'] }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_{{ $loop->iteration }}" value="{{ $flight['id'] }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_{{ $loop->iteration}}" value="{{ $flight['flight_price'] }}">
        @empty
        @endforelse
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">PAGA</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispense with that old HTML-only integration and change to a [current version of PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), using the v2/checkout/orders REST API from your server.

Begin by creating two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You could use the (recently deprecated) Checkout-PHP-SDK for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)